# How to extract a value from a cell if certain criteria is met? (Diagram included) (Excel)

Tags: excel

[I would like a function that is able to do this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8UbIO.png) I've been busting my head with the Index and Match functions but I can't get them to work! Any help is aprecciated. Thanks =')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want to sum all values from column A where column C is equal to TMP. You want to use the SUMIF function.

=SUMIF(C2:C4,"TMP",A2:A4)

Comment: Thanks! Worked like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

The Excel macro to do this is trivial, so I must not be understanding the question.

If I put the following equation in D1...

=IF(C1=C3,A1+A3,)

The contents of D1 = 600 when the contents of C1 and C3 are equivalent.

I think you need more clarity in your question.  What is "C"?  Do you want an Excel macro or VBA? What is the significance of the values in line 2...they seem superfluous.